# C++11 having problems with multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

So I started writting a game, and I want a logger in a different thread. My approach was this: have a class "Logger", run a thread in the constructor, in the thread there's a loop running which is constantly checking a stringstream for data. That stringstream is a static variable, so I run the logger in the entry point of the program, and then whenever I need to log something, I call a static method which writes to the static stringstream, which is being read from every 100ms in the thread. So I'm wondering if this approach is viable in game programming and if it is even a little bit good, how should I approach this?

Tried this, which is failing(somehow somethings throwing an unhandled exception right after Sleep(100), and not continuing on the loop...)

```
class Logger
{
private:
    ofstream out;
    string fileName;
    thread T;
    bool running;

    static stringstream sstream;

    void run();

public:
    Logger();
    ~Logger();

    void stop();

    static void log(string msg);

    void join();
};

stringstream Logger::sstream;

Logger::Logger()
{
    fileName = "log.txt";
    out = ofstream(fileName);
    if (!out.is_open())
    {
        PostQuitMessage(3);
    }
    running = false;
    T = thread(&Logger::run, this);
}

Logger::~Logger()
{
    out.close();
}

void Logger::run()
{
    running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        if (!sstream.str().empty())
        {
            out << sstream.str();
            sstream.clear();
        }
        Sleep(100);
    }
}

void Logger::stop()
{
    running = false;
}

void Logger::log(string msg)
{
    Logger::sstream << "lel" << endl;
}

void Logger::join()
{
    T.join();
}
```

Comment: approach is ok, but you should think about synchronization, what if 2 different threads will try to call `log` method at the very same moment?

Comment: a thread that does logging should probably be detached from main not joined

Comment: "It's not joined" ... um then why do I see T.join in the last function and no detach anywhere :P, BTW i'm not saying you shouldn't just a suggestion

Comment: If there's a method, it doesn't mean that it's being used :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly a immediate problems:

1. There is no synchronization which will lead to undefined behavior. You'll need to create appropriate synchronization, e.g., using a `std::mutex` for you `std::stringstream` (personally, I'd simply use a `std::queue<std::string>` but that's a separate issue.
2. Your logger thread shouldn't poll for input. Instead, it should just `wait()` on a `std::condition_variable` to be `notify_one()`d about available data.
3. Although it is just a `bool`, you `running` flag also need synchronization! It is a data race if any threads a variable which is written by another thread without synchronization. For the `running` flag you might want to use a `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Haven't thought about the second part, is pretty clever. But one question remains, I'm pretty new to multithreading+c++, so how do I use a mutex on a stringstream?

Comment: @VilmantasBašinovas: Well, you'd just lock a mutex before each access to the stream and release it right afterwards. To automate the process you'd use a `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` which is needed anyway by the `std::condition_variable` to wait (you probably want to use `wait_until()` with the predicate checking the stream and the `running` flag). Note, that you need to `notify_one()` when you touch the stream or the `running` flag to get the logging thread out of its wait.

Comment: I know how a mutex works, in theory, but I don't know how to use it practicaly. Like how to implement it in my code... /embarassed